# playframework - Best way to trim a json values

Tags: json, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.4

I am trying to figure out the best and elegant way to tim values on an in coming json.

So for example I have the following json:

```
{
  "firstName": "   foo",
  "lastName": "bar    "
}
```

With the following definitions:

```
case class Someone(firstName:String, lastName: String)
object Someone{
  implicit val someoneReads: Reads[Someone] = (
      (JsPath \ "firstName").read[String] and
      (JsPath \ "lastName").read[String]
    )(Someone.apply _)
}
```

Is there a way to trim the json while reading it? or I need to write  a transformer for that? and if I do, how to write it so it will be generic to trip every json I will provide?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map(_.trim)` for `read[String]` for trim string (universal solution)

```
implicit val someoneReads: Reads[Someone] = (
    (JsPath \ "firstName").read[String].map(_.trim) and
      (JsPath \ "lastName").read[String].map(_.trim)
    )(Someone.apply _)
```

You can implement own Reads[String] with trimmed string also

```
def trimmedString(path: JsPath): Reads[String] = Reads.at[String](path).map(_.trim)

implicit val someoneReads: Reads[Someone] = (
  trimmedString(JsPath \ "firstName") and trimmedString(JsPath \ "lastName")    
  )(Someone.apply _)
```

For a more familiar view of code you may implement implicit conversion

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions

class JsPathHelper(val path: JsPath) {
  def trimmedString: Reads[String] = Reads.at[String](path).map(_.trim)
}
implicit def toJsPathHelper(path: JsPath): JsPathHelper = new JsPathHelper(path)

implicit val someoneReads: Reads[Someone] = (
  (JsPath \ "firstName").trimmedString and
  (JsPath \ "lastName").trimmedString
)(Someone.apply _)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is my current solution.. but I was looking to a more generic solution..I have lots of Reads and I which to solve this from everyone and not add this mapping to every line. At least this is what I wish to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your own reads[String] based on the default one, and then use macros:

```
object Someone {

  implicit val trimStringReads: Reads[String] = Reads.StringReads.map(_.trim)

  implicit val someoneReads: Reads[Someone] = Json.reads[Someone]
}
```